# TFS unfolds PBIs in Backlog

Tags: tfs

When I refresh the Backlogview of our TFS 2017 (but the Issue was there with TFS 2015 as well), there are some Product Backlog Items, which are unfolded, showing the contained work items.
This somehow messes up the shown forecast. If I close those PBIs so that their WIs are no longer shown, the forecast disappears is not shown at all.

Is there something I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't do anything wrong and I tested in both TFS 2017 and TFS 2015 to confirm your issue. It does show like that.

This issue happens in the following situation:

Look at the pictures below, I have 2 PBIs that has child tasks. When I fold 'mmm', the 'Sprint2' forecast line won't disappear. When I fold 'jjj', the 'Sprint3' forecast line will disappear. It is hidden together with the 'Task2' under 'jjj'.

[image]

**After fold:**

[image]

As a workaround to solve this issue, you could drag workitems like 'jjj' to other place. Change the order of it. **Do not let workitems who have child tasks show above the Sprint forecast line**.

Comment: I have placed the Issue to the Microsoft Forum and a Bugreport now Exists.May be you would like to vote there too ;-)
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46718/forecasting-line-disappered-when-folder-the-pbi-up.html

Comment: @Rainer I have voted it. Do you have any other questions and Could you please mark my reply as the answer if you accept it.